# Web Api Understanding

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I was wondering how Do I pass a string as a paramter and how .net determines which get is applied and returned.

I am trying

```
 http://localhost:55304/api/WebPortal/Get/System.WorkItem.Incident
```

But its not working just get a resource is not found. The below is in my WebPortal Controller.

```
   private WebPortEnterpriseManagementDa _da = new WebPortEnterpriseManagementDa();
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }

    public ManagedType Get(string name)
    {

        ManagedType items = _da.GetManagedType(name);

        return items;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the mark up whoever did that ?

Comment: If you enter code or a tag, The markup is set automatically. Only if you want specific markup, you can see the help: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to append a parameter to the URL:

```
url + "&name=" + param;
```

Comment: im asking for a solution within the browser url so can test it not code behind thanks

Comment: That is in the URL. Add `&name=whateverParameterYouWantHere` to the end of your URL. I did it in code format for clarity .. haha

Comment: is it cause the way im doing the method, cause i removed the other gets left that one their and its still saying not found does a get have to return a string i thought it could just reutrn an object?

Comment: You probably want to return a JSON object, so you're doing it right. If you are receiving an error when trying to use your Get method you may want to take a look at your routes.

Comment: Are you testing your API using Postman? If not, you may want to take a look at it.

Comment: my routes are just the default 


            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }


is their something i need to do to add in my WebPortal Controller?

Comment: Well, your URLs don't correspond to that route, so you would need to amend that.

Comment: api/WebPortal/Get/System.WorkItem.Incident doesn't look like controller/action/id to me :)

Comment: That is what I was asking slippy? what is the correct way to pass that the string for that method.

Comment: You might need to ask another question on routing, the last time I made an API I dealt with all the routing by splitting the request URL in my code and doing it that way, so I wouldn't be the best person to ask.

Comment: just trying to slippy still have the 90 min rule hate that on a new account

Comment: ASKED THE question here 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25325631/web-api-routing-understanding